# VMware non Persistent Disk

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I Have some vms with non persistent disk.
Changes made to the disk are discarded after shutdown or reset the vm. 
Is it possible to discard changes to disk after guest restart or guest shut down?

Thanks in advance

Editted:

I want every day to discard changes made to the disk. 
Currently I am doing that with "hard reset" from vcenter (the disk is independent non persistent).
I want to be able to discard changes with restart guest and no hard reset.

Comment: What exactly you want to do and why, please explain your use case.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply restarting the guest will not wipe the nonpersistent data, only a poweroff or a hard reset will do. According to the [vmware documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-E1D541D1-DF96-467A-89B7-E84F83B2563D.html):

> Changes to disks in nonpersistent mode are discarded when you turn off or reset the virtual machine. With nonpersistent mode, you can restart the virtual machine with a virtual disk in the same state every time. Changes to the disk are written to and read from a redo log file that is deleted when you turn off or reset the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks. And is the machine can damaged if I hard power off everyday?

Comment: No, a proper power down (I mean anything except 'pulling the plug') should not damage the virtual machine in any way.